# Manually setting return_to with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication, devise

I am currently using Devise to authenticate users on my app.  It's working great for the most point, but I am having trouble with a specific action:

view:

```
<p id="save"><%= link_to "Save", new_save_path, :remote => true %></p>
```

saves_controller.rb:

```
def new
  if user_signed_in?
    @save = Save.create(:user_id => current_user.id)
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html "save", "Saved!"
    end
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, :notice => "You need to sign in to do that."
  end
end
```

As you can see, because the action is an ajax one, I can't use the traditional `before_filter :authenticate_user!` method.  So instead I am redirecting the user to the sign in page.

The problem is, I want to automatically redirect the user back to the previous page when they logged in.

I understand I can do this with the `session[:"user.return_to"]` but I'm having trouble setting it. How can I do this? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the session key is `:"#{scope}_return_to`, which will be simply `:user_return_to` for a `User` class.

Comment: Thanks! I used this in conjunction with `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` as mentioned in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3921517/337903.